# invoke shell command from within Aptana/ Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aptana

I'm trying to add a feature to Aptana, and this feature requires that I find out where the gems are on the system.  In ruby I would run a command like...

```
gem_folder_path = `rvm gemdir`
```

In java obviously there are more factors to deal with, but it seems that the java solution I've been trying to implement won't work within the bounds of the eclipse/ Aptana IDE (I've tested it standalone and it works fine in my helloworld.java file).  Are shell commands disabled or something?

Here's my current java solution which is not functional.

```
public static String getGemsDirectory()
{
    try
    {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("which ruby");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                                        InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                                        InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));


        String s;
        String commandOutput = "";
        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(s);
            commandOutput += s;
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((String s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(s);
            commandOutput += s;
        }

        int statusCode = proc.exitValue();
        return commandOutput;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial will show u how to run native OS commands. Works for me from Eclipse/Tomcat and just Java
http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/java/22-Native-Apps.pdf

Comment: Thankyou for the tut, but that tut contains the solution I found on google.  The problem seems specific to either large java apps or specifically eclipse plugins.